# Route Audio from Android Phone to PC via USB?

Tags: android, audio, usb

I want to route audio from an Android app I am developing to a PC via a standard USB cable. I have found some sources discussing native USB Audio support in Android Lollipop, but am unable to find any documentation or example code online.

Is this possible? Preferably, Windows should recognize the device as a standard microphone without the need for any extra drivers or software.

Thanks!